# AS3 How to set boundries to Mouse Down drag?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to AS3 and I have a square(1200w) that's bigger than the stage(200w). Right now you can keep dragging it left and right as far as you possibly can. How can I set a limit/boundry to how much of the square you can drag? So that it can't be dragged beyond it's maximum width?

[Here's an image](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/6677/boundary.jpg)

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    square_mc.x = mouseX;
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}
```

**Please note I do not want to use the `startdrag()` method.**

Comment: And why not use startdrag()?? I think it would be the simplest way to achieve this result, and you know, is the native way in flash to actually drag stuff around...

Comment: 9 Years on and the image link is broken... For historic purposes, please consider reuploading the original image if it's still available.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image, assume that `mc` refers to the blue box.

```
var ox:Number = 0;

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    ox = mc.mouseX;

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mc.x = mc.parent.mouseX - ox;

    if(mc.x > 0) mc.x = 0;
    if(mc.x + mc.width < stage.stageWidth) mc.x = stage.stageWidth - mc.width;
}
```

Hopefully this is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks Marty, but hmm it's not working very well. It flickers to the set boundaries but you can still drag it beyond the set boundaries.

Comment: Give that a try - amended so that the box won't actually move until the boundary checks are made.

Comment: That's not working at all now. I've updated my question a bit, so now it reads "How can I set a limit/boundry to how much of the square you can drag? So that it can't be dragged beyond it's maximum width?". Maybe that explains what I'm trying to do better?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to apply a limit to the area on which you can actually click to begin dragging the block?

Comment: Ah, so you don't want the left hand side of the box to go to the right of the stage's left edge, and you don't want the right hand side of the box to go left of the stage's right edge, correct?

Comment: @ Marty Basically if the block's left point needs to be the furthest to fit on the left hand side of the stage, where as the right point need to fit on the right hand side of the stage.... sorry this is such a poor explanation, i'll try to find an example online to show you